# Same file type, different icon. How to reset it

Tags: icons, file-type

I have a folder with Python source code. All files are being opened with double click with Text Editor, also the "problematic" one. All files have .py extension.

The "problematic" file has a green Qt icon and I didn't find a way to remove it. Reset and set default application (that now is Text Editor) didn't help.

Ubuntu 20.04

[image]

```
$ file -i MyHTMLParser.py 
MyHTMLParser.py: text/x-python; charset=us-ascii

$ file MyHTMLParser.py 
MyHTMLParser.py: Python script, ASCII text executable

$ file -i Scanner.py 
Scanner.py: text/x-python; charset=utf-8

$ file Scanner.py 
Scanner.py: Python script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable, with CRLF line terminators
```

First line of MyHTMLParser.py:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
```

First line of Scanner.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
```

text/x-qml MIME type is shown from Properties

[image]

That type is not present in

```
/etc/mime.types
```

I really can't understand where that information is stored.

**UPDATED 'N'**

I wrote a script that remove all \r\n line endings and UTF-8 characters. Now Scanner_new.py has the same type of MyHTMLParser.py, but nothing is changed:

```
$ file -i MyHTMLParser.py 
MyHTMLParser.py: text/x-python; charset=us-ascii

$ file MyHTMLParser.py 
MyHTMLParser.py: Python script, ASCII text executable

$ file -i Scanner_new.py 
Scanner_new.py: text/x-python; charset=us-ascii

$ file Scanner_new.py 
Scanner_new.py: Python script, ASCII text executable
```

[image]

Comment: Could you run the `file` commands on both files ? In linux the file extension (here .py) havr no meaning. The file type is found by analyzing the start of the file - for script code by looking at the she-bang in first line, so maybe also check that for differences.

Comment: Updated OP. Maybe the problem is that Scanner.py was edited also on Windows? It is a multiplatform application, but where is stored that information??? I'll write a script that replace \r\n line endings with \r, then try to remove UTF-8 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem isn't the line ending or the characters set (UTF-8, ASCII...). If in the file there is the sentence "import QtCore" (never mind if as start line or in the middle of the file) the icon will be the Qt one.

[image]

**I don't known who is responsible for the parsing**, as soon as I click Ctrl+S (with or without "import QtCore") the icon changes